# SQL Grouping same data multiple ways

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to group data into multiple groups. Each grouping is a sum of the data. However, with each grouping, if an item is a member of multiple groups, and one group gets left out, the item needs to be removed from any other groups it would be part of.

For Example:

```
CREATE TABLE #test (Item VARCHAR(1), Group1 BIT, Group2 BIT, Units INT)

INSERT INTO #test (Item, Group1, Group2, Units)
VALUES
('A', 1, 0, 2),
('B', 1, 1, 2),
('C', 1, 1, 2),
('D', 1, 1, 2),
('E', 0, 1, 2)
```

If we assume that Group1 requires 7 total units in order to be returned, and Group2 requires 9 total units to be returned.

I have this so far:

```
--Everything that is NOT NULL will be excluded
Select *
FROM #test t
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT t.Group1, SUM(t.Units) AS TotalUnits
    FROM #test t
    WHERE t.Group1 = 1
    GROUP BY t.Group1
    HAVING SUM(Units) < 7
) g1 ON g1.Group1 = t.Group1
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
    SELECT t.Group2, SUM(t.Units) AS TotalUnits
    FROM #test t
    WHERE t.Group2 = 1
    GROUP BY t.Group2
    HAVING SUM(Units) < 9
) g2 ON g2.Group2 = t.Group2
```

If you run this, you'll see that :

> B,C,D,E fail the test of Group2, because they sum up to 8 units, and
>   they needed to be at least 9.
>
> A, B, C, D succeed Group1, because they add up to 8 units, and they
>   just needed to have 7 or more.

However, I need this to be changed, so that both fail.

Because B, C, D failed in Group2, they would need to be excluded from being considered for Group1.

So really, Group1 would only be item A, for 2 units, which would fail because it is less than the 7 required for group1.

Hard to explain, but basically I need the same data to be grouped multiple ways, so that if it fails in one grouping, it is left out of the second grouping, and vice versa.

For output, I would expect something like this. Note the total units for Group1 is 2, since B, C, D no longer count toward it's sum. Technically I would guess the TotalUnits of Group2 should also be 2, since when group1 failed, items B, C, D no longer can count toward it's sum. Basically trying to evaluate both groups, intersecting, at the same time, where the sum of one is dependent on what happened with the sum of the other.

```
Item    Group1  Group2  Units   Group1  TotalUnits  Group2  TotalUnits
A         1        0      2       1        2         NULL     NULL
B         1        1      2       1        2          1        8
C         1        1      2       1        2          1        8
D         1        1      2       1        2          1        8
E         0        1      2      NULL     NULL        1        8
```

Comment: Hi, yes it's hard to explain but good explain was excepted output if you have thoses put on your query

Comment: You've done a great job posting proper sample data, but if you could [edit] your question to also post the expected output of this data, that would help us understand the question so much better.

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need is to add this to the end of your query:

```
where g1.Group1=1 and g2.Group2=1
```

Note that you "Draw" the group1/2 info from the subquery tables, which return NULL when the `HAVING` filters them out.

Also note that your `CREATE TABLE` statement provided is missing the 4th column with zeroes...

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             sum(group1 * units) over () as group1_units,
             sum(group2 * units) over () as group2_units
      from #test t
     ) t
where (group1 = 1 and group1_units >= 7) or
      (group2 = 1 and group2_units >= 9);
```

Comment: No. Most of the elements of Group1 shouldn't count to the sum of Group1, since they failed out of Group2. So really, the sum of group1 would only be "2", because only item A was not part of the failed Group2.

Comment: @fullstrum . . . Your problem statement is:  "If we assume that Group1 requires 7 total units in order to be returned, and Group2 requires 9 total units to be returned."